# pip install --upgrade is installing my "local" version suffixed packages

Tags: python, pip

During development I build and push feature branch versions of my package that look like: `1.2.3+mybranch`.

So I'll have packages named `1.2.3`, `1.2.3+mybranch` and `1.2.4+mybranch`, and `1.2.4`.

The problem is it seems pip has no problem installing a package with a `+suffix` when doing a regular `pip install --upgrade`.

I don't want pip to do that.

Is there a way I can have only release versions installed with `pip install --upgrade`? I would think pip would do this by default.

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer in a comment here: [How to correctly create Python feature branch releases in development? (pip and PEP-440)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69344089/how-to-correctly-create-python-feature-branch-releases-in-development-pip-and)

I just needed to include a proper pre-release version.

So `1.2.3+mybranch` should be `1.2.3-dev0+mybranch`. Now pip will ignore my feature branch versions by default because it knows they are pre-releases.